# Remove all files older than the specified one

Tags: powershell

I want to remove all txt extension file that has last write date older than the last write date of the current one (00007.txt is the current file) but can't figure out a way yet

```
$a = (get-item C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\test\*.txt).lastwritetime

$b = (get-item C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\test\00007.txt).lastwritetime


while ($a[$i] -lt $b)
{
$i++
remove-item $a
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just enumerate the items with Get-ChildItem, filter with Where-Object, and pipe directly to Remove-Item:

```
$b = (get-item C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\test\00007.txt).lastwritetime

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\test\*.txt | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime -lt $b
} | Remove-Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Short version

```
$dt = (gi "C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\test\00007.txt").lastwritetime
gci "C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\test\" -file -Filter "*.txt" | ? LastWriteTime -lt $dt | ri
```